# How to define a promise chain without using then method

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I already looked for similar questions, but they are related to JQuery or any other library.

First, I wrote this:

```
const printIn1Sec = (value) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(value);
      resolve();
    }, 1000)
  });
};
```

And used it in this way:

```
printIn1Sec(1)
.then(() => printIn1Sec(2))
.then(() => printIn1Sec(3));
```

I think `then` is very important, because it allows us to execute something as soon as the promise is resolved.

But I was looking for something like this:

```
printIn1Sec(1)
.printIn1Sec(2)
.printIn1Sec(3);
```

I noticed I needed an object with access to this `printIn1Sec` method. So I defined a class:

```
class Printer extends Promise {
  in1Sec(v) {
    return this.then(() => this.getPromise(v));
  }

  getPromise(value) {
    return new Printer(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(value);
        resolve();
      }, 1000)
    })
  }
}
```

And used it this way:

```
Printer.resolve().in1Sec(1).in1Sec(2).in1Sec(3);
```

I had to `resolve` the Promise from the beginning, in order to the start the chain. But it still bothers me.

Do you think, is there a way to get it working like the following?

```
printIn1Sec(1).printIn1Sec(2).printIn1Sec(3);
```

I was thinking in a new class or method, that could receive these values, store them, and finally start resolving the chain.
But it would require to call an aditional method at the end, to init with the flow.

Comment: Have you tried [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)? It is not going to be just like what you want but I recommend you checking it if you hadn't.

Comment: While `async/await` is the obvious answer, I'm curious to see whether any trick exists that will (even clumsily) allow chaining in such a way. I doubt it but let's see. I'd recommend the  OP don't accept an answer immediately.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you really wanted to create a chainable interface as in your question, this would do it:

```js
const printIn1Sec = (function() {

  function setTimeoutPromise(timeout) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
  }

  function printIn1Sec(value, promise) {
    const newPromise = promise
      .then(() => setTimeoutPromise(1000))
      .then(() => console.log(value));

    return {
      printIn1Sec(value) {
        return printIn1Sec(value, newPromise);
      },
    };
  }

  return value => printIn1Sec(value, Promise.resolve());
}());

printIn1Sec(1)
  .printIn1Sec(2)
  .printIn1Sec(3);
```

We just hide all the promise creation and chaining in an internal function. I split the code into smaller functions to make it a bit nicer looking.

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking in a way to create an object with a method without defining a class, but I didn't know it was possible or not. You did this inside function `printIn1Sec(value, promise)` for the return, right? As I understand, the first call refers to the `const` variable, but the following are objects calling `printIn1Sec(value)`, which is finally using `printIn1Sec(value, promise)`. Is that correct?

Comment: Yep, that's correct. Objects can just be created with [object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

Answer (score 6):

You can try `async` and `await`

```js
const printIn1Sec = (value) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(value);
        resolve();
    }, 1000)
  });
};

async function fun(){
  await printIn1Sec(1);
  await printIn1Sec(2);
  await printIn1Sec(3);
}

fun();
```

Comment: How does this get 3 upvotes and I get -2?  Not only does my answer cover async/await *and* gives him the general solution for what he wants, your answer is literally "use syntactic sugar to do *exactly* what you explicitly said you *started out with* and don't want to do" .... sometimes I really don't get this site at all....

Comment: @LeroyStav I didn't downvote your answer. But I think people here prefer to see code examples, more than useful links.

Comment: I did not mean to imply you did, sorry!